RegEx: Python (findall). Order of elements in OR statement resulting in different output
I am trying to get my head around regular expressions and was playing with some examples trying to see what it comes out at. I am struggling to understand how the order of element in OR (|) impacts the output of the following code

import re 
uni = "University of Sheffield" 
first = re.findall(".*U|S.*U|S",uni) 
second = re.findall(".*U|S.*S|U",uni)
third = re.findall(".*S|U.*S|U",uni)


if I print first, second and third variable I get following
first -> ['U', 'S']
second -> ['U']
third -> ['University of S']

I don't understand why the output for each is the way it is. I assumed it should be the same and it should be ['University of S']. I was wondering if someone would help me understand why is it interpreted differently for each of these 3 cases?
Thank you!

.*S and U.*S are the only expressions that could possibly match 'University of S', so the OR ordering is somewhat moot.

Thank you Finn and Mark, it makes sense to me now!

It has to do with the order of operations involving OR (|).
By default, OR takes everything either side of it, so your 3 expressions would be as follows:
.*U OR S.*U OR S
.*U OR S.*S OR U
.*S OR U.*S OR U
This means that for the first one, your code does find anything/nothing  followed by a U (.*U). It does not find an S followed by anything/nothing followed by a U (S.*U). Then it does find an S (S). Hence the result, ["U", "S"]
Similarly, for the second expression, your code does find anything/nothing followed by a U (.*U). It does not find an S followed by anything/nothing followed by an S (S.*S). Then it does not find a second U (U). Hence the result, ["U"]
For the third expression, your code does not find anything/nothing followed by an S (.*S). Then it does find a U followed by anything/nothing ('niversity of ') followed by an S (U.*S). Then it does not find another U. Hence the result ["University of S"].
I assume you meant your expression to be:
.* (U OR S) .* (U OR S)
To write this as valid regex, it should be:
.*(?U|S).*(?U|S)

You can also do it with match groups (...) instead of non-matching groups (?...).
However, best practice in this case would be that you use a character class. It is written with square brackets, and matches any one of all the characters put inside. To use it in this example, it would be:
.*[US].*[US]


an OR(|) stops on the first match, not the longest.  Once a match is made, only the remaining string is checked during .findall:
In the first case, .*U or S.*U or S is checked:

.*U matches U.
In the remaining string (niversity of Sheffiel), S matches S.
In the remaining string (heffield), none of the patterns match.

In the second case, .*U or S.*S or U is checked:

.*U matches U.
In the remaining string (niversity of Sheffield), none of patterns match.

In the third case, .*S or U.*S or U is checked:

.*S matches University of S.
In the remaining string (heffield), none of the patterns match.

